# JS callback to Vaadin component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a JS component (SigPlot) that I need to read click values from.   I have instantiated SigPlot inside of a VerticalLayout, where I also instantiate a DIV to pass to the SigPlot constructor.   I am not sure if this is a valid way, but it works.
Now I need to read CLICKS but I am having troubles finding correct way to do this.   Can someone pass some words of wisdom?

In my constructor for my VIEW, it use addAttachListener to start my JS code using.

```
div.addAttachListener(e->{
    e.getUI().getPage().executeJs("myInit($0)",div);
});
```

How can I register a click listener to this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it's just a regular DOM event listener, then something like this should work:

```
div.getElement().addEventListener("click", event -> Notification.show("Clicked"));
```

If you need to do something on a more granular level, then your might want to expose callbacks as `@ClientCallable` and then use `executeJs` to run some short JavaScript snippets to set up listeners that delegate to those methods.